# jQuery: on class click: toggle div and on somewhere else click: hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have 3 `<a>` which all have the class `.info-btn` with a `data="1"` parameter (from 1 till 3).

if you click on an `<a>` with class `.info-btn` it should get the `data=*` paramter in var `x` and should creat with `$('.div-info-'+x).fadeToggle("fast");` a visible div with the class `.div-info-*` (* = 1,2 or 3; each class are exists)

And what i else wanted:  if the click is somewhere else as on the `<a class=".info-btn"` it should hide the div which get visible.

what i created and what is usable..

```
   $(".info-btn").click(function(e){ 
        var x = $(this).attr('data');
        $('.div-info-'+x).fadeToggle("fast");
    });`
```

but only for toggle on class click, but not for hide on click somewhere else.

my code what i tried for the other thing..

```
$(document.body).click(function(e){

            if ((".info-btn").click())
            {
                var x = $(this).attr('data');
                $('.div-info-'+x).fadeToggle("fast");
            }
            else (!(".info-btn").click())
            {
                var x = $(this).attr('data');
                $('.div-info-'+x).fadeToggle("fast");
            }

        });
```

i hope someone of you could help me and sorry for my bad english guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.data()` to store which element was clicked. Latter on document click, check if target is neither `div` nor its parent(optional), hide it.

*HTML*

```
<a class="info-btn" data="1" href="#">INFO</a>

<div class="div-info-1">Sortierung der Kategorien wird automatisch drei mal täglich ausgeführt. Sortierung Ende Juni 2013 anpassen!</div>
```

*JavaScript*

```
$(".info-btn").click(function (e) {
    var x = $(this).attr('data');
    $('.div-info-' + x).show();
    $(".info-btn").data('clickedDivId', '.div-info-' + x);
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('document clicked');
    var target = e.target;
    var clickedDiv = $(".info-btn").data('clickedDivId');
    if (!$(target).is(clickedDiv) && !$(target).parents().is(clickedDiv)) {
        $(clickedDiv).hide();
    }
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6V9A5/2/)

Comment: `<a class="info-btn" data="1">INFO</a>
  <div class="div-info-1">INFO WHICH SHOULD BE VISIBLE ON CLICK</div>`

this in an `<a>` no div, it looks like your code isnt usable for this, i am trying to fix it, but i am not so good in jquery and in english :P

Comment: and my script console get every time the error code 'Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'click'' while `$(document).click(function(e) {` isn't `$(document.body).click(function(e) {`

Comment: thanks mate now i get it :) `$(document).ready(function() 
{
 
 var x = 0;

 $('body').click(function(evt)
 {
  if(evt.target.id == "info")
          return;

       $(".div-info-"+x).hide("fast");

 });
 
    $(".info-btn").click(function(e)
 { 
  $('#div-info').hide("fast");

     x = $(this).attr('data');
     $('.div-info-'+x).fadeToggle("fast");
    }); 


 
});`

Comment: @David, I have posted woking demo

Comment: my bad i didn't see it, but your code also helped me to fix my problem :)

thank you

btw: do you know how to use the `.hide()` methode with a `.fadeToggle("fast")` animation?